# how to pass java script variable to php

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to pass this sid variable from php-> jquery/ajax ->php. So, for now I've created sid='1' and then passed it to jquery/ajax and then I am trying to pass sid to code.php to make a database update each time the link is clicked. But, I am not able to find an update in database. Please help!

```
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="click">click here</a>
<?php
$sid='1';
?>
<script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){

    var sid=<?php echo $sid; ?>
    $('#click').click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var request = $.ajax(
        {    
             type: "POST",
             url: "code.php",
             data:{source1:sid},
             success: function() {
                window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
             }                               
        });
   });
});
</script>
</body>
```

This is code.php

```
<?php
// Connection to database
   $sid = $_POST['source1'];

  $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample");
  mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE e set count=(count+1) WHERE sid='$sid'");

  mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: `I am not able to find an update in database` check what data you sent through post and confirm if data is updated in database

Comment: Do you perhaps have a JavaScript error you're not telling us about?  I'm betting there's a syntax error hiding in the line where you assign sid. Look at the source in your browser.

Comment: Nope! there is no javascript error

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be a easy way try it:

```
<body>
<a href="#" id="click">click here</a>
<?php
$sid='1';
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$( "#click" ).click(function() { 
var sid = <?php echo $sid ?>; // getting id from above
$.ajax({
       type: "POST", //post method
       url: "code.php",  //destination file
       data:"source1="+sid, // sending source1=sid the data
       success: function()
       {
     window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
       },
     });
  });
  </script>
  </body>
```